# show/hide gridview within a gridview with linkbutton

Tags: javascript, vb.net, gridview, toggle, linkbutton

I am trying to show a gridview of questions and some of the questions have more details which can be shown by clicking on the questionnumber (linkbutton) and a gridview will appear with those details directly under the question number. 
 I can get this to work with an image not the linkbutton, but I am not able to display an image with each question, i have to toggle it on/off with the row databound code.  This is when it stops working.  Ive tried several things, using the javascript as a function, trying to enclose in a div, etc and I am stuck.  I believe it is something in the javascript somewhere but I am out of ideas. I am open to using image or hyperlink just as long as it can be toggled on/off and will show the grid upon click.  Thanks!

backend:

```
Private Sub grdChanges_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdChanges.RowDataBound
    Select Case e.Row.RowType
        Case DataControlRowType.DataRow

Dim rowDat As Model.DocumentModel.DocChangeHistory = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, Model.DocumentModel.DocChangeHistory)

Dim lbuttonQuestionText As LinkButton = e.Row.FindControl("linkButtonQuestionNum") ' when click show detailed gridview

Dim lblQuestionText As Label = e.Row.FindControl("lblQuestionNum") 'No details available just show label

If rowDat.details_needed = 1 Then
        lblQuestionText.Visible = False
        lbuttonQuestionText.Visible = True
        Dim QuestionId As Long = convert.ToInt64(grdChanges.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Value) 
        Dim gvQuestionDetails As GridView = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("gvQuestionDetails"), GridView)
        Using hDal As New HistoryDAL(CurrentUserId, ProjectID)
            'grabbing information from the database works fine
             gvQuestionDetails.DataSource = <blah Blah> 
             gvQuestionDetails.DataBind()
        End Using
Else  'no details needed just show regular question number as label not linkbutton
        lblQuestionText.Visible = True
        lbuttonQuestionText.Visible = false 
End If
```

ascx:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#" ItemStyle-CssClass="col-400px" ItemStyle-Width="25px" SortExpression="QuestionNum"  >

<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="lblQuestionNum" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("question_id")%>' Visible="false" ToolTip='<%#Eval("question_text")%>'></asp:Label>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkButtonQuestionNum" runat="server"  Text='<%#Bind("question_id")%>' Visible="false" BorderStyle-Right="None" ToolTip='<%#Eval("question_text")%>' />
<asp:Panel ID="pnlTableQuestion" runat="server" Style="display: none">                           
<asp:GridView ID="gvQuestionDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="col_name" HeaderText="Column" />
       <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="comments" HeaderText="Comments" />
   </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
       $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + 
        $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "images/minus_Expand.jpg");
    });

$("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/plus_Collapse.jpg");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a fix in the Javascript.  The best example is here:

Comment: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Collapsible-Nested-GridView-with-Paging-using-ASPNet.aspx